# How to get max of null & number in sql as null?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

Consider a sample SQL table with two columns and values inserted as

```
INSERT INTO `over_all` (`team_number`, `day_1`) VALUES
('J091', '01:00:00'),
('J091', '01:02:00');

INSERT INTO `over_all` (`team_number`, `day_1`) VALUES
('J092', 'null'),
('J092', '02:02:00');
```

Now when I use

```
SELECT `over_all`.`team_number`,
        max(`over_all`.`day_1`) as 'maximum'
FROM `over_all`
GROUP BY `over_all`.`team_number`
ORDER BY 'maximum'
```

**Question:**

> I want this to return the max of J092 as *null*.

**DATABASE Used**

> Server version: 10.1.25-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Comment: You can't use aliases in `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` cluase.

Comment: Your question is not clear what do you mean with "I want this to return the max of J092 as null."   ?   show the expected  result in tabular form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END`:

```
SELECT team_number,
    case when max(day_1 is null) = 0 then max(day_1) else null end as maximum
FROM over_all
GROUP BY team_number
ORDER BY maximum
```

Try it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/101143/2/0